# Raw key board listener (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I have a RawKeyboardListener widget that I use to control the TV through the remote buttons and it works fine.

But when you press the center button for a long time, it repeats the function. I just want to cancel the long-press process and work only with one press.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class RawKeyboardListenerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final FocusNode focusNode;
  final void Function(int) remoteControlKeys;

  const RawKeyboardListenerWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.focusNode,
    required this.remoteControlKeys,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawKeyboardListener(

      focusNode: focusNode,

      onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {
        if (event is RawKeyDownEvent && event.data is RawKeyEventDataAndroid) {

          RawKeyDownEvent rawKeyDownEvent = event;
          RawKeyEventDataAndroid rawKeyEventDataAndroid = rawKeyDownEvent.data as RawKeyEventDataAndroid;
          remoteControlKeys(rawKeyEventDataAndroid.keyCode);

          if (rawKeyEventDataAndroid.keyCode == 23) {

             //_handleCenterOrEnterKeyPress();

          } else if (rawKeyEventDataAndroid.keyCode == 20) {

           //_handleDownKeyPress();

          } else if (rawKeyEventDataAndroid.keyCode == 19) {

             //_handleUpKeyPress();

          } else if (rawKeyEventDataAndroid.keyCode == 22) {

             //_handleRightKeyPress();

          } else if (rawKeyEventDataAndroid.keyCode == 21) {

             //_handleLeftKeyPress();

          }
        }
      },
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RawKeyEvent's property `repeat` can be used here. Here is a barebones example illustrating how you could use the `repeat` property to avoid repeated calls to your function.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawKeyboardListener(
      focusNode: focusNode,
      onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {
        // If there is a event you don't want to repeat,
        // check if it is a repeat event.
        if (!event.repeat) {

          // Consider checking if the event is a key-up/key-down event, 
          // as otherwise, it might trigger the same function twice.
          if(event is RawKeyDownEvent) {
            // Do your action here, to trigger the action on key down.
            print("${event.physicalKey.debugName} - Down");

          } else if(event is RawKeyUpEvent) {
            // Or, do your action here, to trigger the action on key up.
            print("${event.physicalKey.debugName} - Up");
          }
        }
      },
      child: child,
    );
  }
```

Try to apply this pattern to your use case, hope it helps!